# php equivalent of rs.conf() in mongodb ?

Tags: php, mongodb

how can I get the same result as rs.conf() gives. I am trying to get the replicaset node's status through php. So I was wondering if I can get the same output as rs.conf() gives in mongodb shell ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using `MongoDB::execute`

Example :

```
$db->execute('return rs.status();');
```

Comment: Unfortunately execute is deprecated since MongoDB 3.0+, so see Sammaye answer.  Source: http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.execute.php

Answer (score 1):

You can do it via JS or you can actually go to the database directly via `command`:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/replSetGetStatus/#replSetGetStatus

```
$db->command(array('replSetGetStatus' => 1));
```

Should be slightly faster than `eval`ing code and holding a JS global lock.